# AJAX: fading in images

Tags: html, ajax

I've noticed the images on [mashable.com](http://mashable.com) fade in as I scroll down the page. I guess they are loaded with AJAX to reduce the page weight in the beginning.

Is there a jquery plugin for doing this? What's the best way to add this feature to my website?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's called *lazy loading* of images. There's a  [jQuery plugin here](http://www.appelsiini.net/2007/9/lazy-load-images-jquery-plugin). There are probably many more if you have a look around...